# Laravel Driver [] is not supported

Tags: php, laravel

FileSystem :

```
'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],

        'shares' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => public_path('shares'),
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],

        's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET'),
            'region' => env('AWS_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
        ],

    ],
```

My controller :

```
public function store(Request $request) {
        $rules = [
            'user_id'           => 'required|exists:users,id',
            'patient_case_id'   => 'required|exists:patient_cases,id',
            'shared_with'       => 'required|exists:users,id',
        ];

        $this->validate($request, $rules);

        $data = $request->all();
        $data['shared_file'] = $request->file('file')->store('shares/'.$data["user_id"], $data["shared_file"]->getClientOriginalName());

        $newShare = WayneRooney::create($data);
        return $this->showOne($newShare, 201);
    }
```

if i leave store method empty, it works and writes file in shares folder in public path with a unique id. But i want to write file with original name under the shares/{USER_ID} folder.

how can i do this ?

Comment: Did you mean to use `storeAs(...)` instead of `store(...)`? Which version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: @sisve yes, i found it :) thank you sisve. You can write as an answer, if you want

Comment: Try `putFileAs` OR `storeAs()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you would not like a file name to be automatically assigned to your stored file, you may use the  `storeAs` method, which receives the path, the file name, and the (optional) disk as its arguments:

```
$path = $request->file('avatar')->storeAs(
     'avatars', $request->user()->id
);
```

you may also use the `putFileAs` method on the Storage facade, which will perform the same file manipulation as the example above:

```
$path = Storage::putFileAs(
     'avatars', $request->file('avatar'), $request->user()->id
);
```

Hope this fixed your issue!